# Simplest way to take an Ember application down for maintenance

Tags: ember.js, amazon-s3

I have an Ember.js application being served from S3, uploaded using ember-cli-deploy. It has a Rails backend that I take down for maintenance from time to time. During this time I would like my ember application to redirect every route to an "undergoing maintenance" page.

Can I do this within the Ember framework, or am I better off temporarily replacing index.html on S3 with a static file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve within your Ember application with a little bit of work.

If your API server returns an identifiable status, let's say a [`503` code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4), you can use a rule for your API calls to redirect to your `maintenance` route using route `actions`, or use the already loaded content.
This allows your Ember application to serve the pages with static or cached data to remain available for seamless browsing, improving the UX.
This, of course, is fine if your downtime is rather low (a couple of seconds).

SEO wise, if you also want to make content temporarily unavailable to spiders, you may want to set a custom rule on your web server (nginx, apache...). This also avoids loading the whole Ember stack.

Answer (score 2):

well, the simplest way would be the way that you suggested (replacing index). However, I am giving you another scenario which you can do if you like but it takes some time to implement.

**Using beforeModel()**

I am not sure if what you are using for authentication and authorization, however, this can help you. For instance, you can just get Session which needs to be validated by Token ( in my case from Server ) and if it's invalid I will redirect everybody to a single page which is login now but you can change it to UC.

```
// route/login.js // this can be in other page as well
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  beforeModel() {
    if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      this.transitionTo('index');  // as you can see if session is authenticated I will redirect it to index but if not all pages will remain in the same page which is login. 
    }
  }
});
```

so in your application.js you can easily

```
this.get('session')
```

and then you can authorize it if it's ok then you can redirect your user to appropriate page but if it's not you may want to redirect it somewhere else.

keep in mind if you want to invalidate session you can easily use

```
session.invalidate();
```

In short, you can easily make your token API or whatever you sent to your Ember application from server inaccessible so Ember cannot resolve it will redirect to another page.

hope I can explain properly and you understand what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Create an initializer which reopens Ember.Route and transitions to your 'down for maintenance' route in the beforeModel hook (before calling super):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var initialize = function(/* container, app */) {
Ember.Route.reopen({
    beforeModel: function() {
        this.transitionTo('down-for-maintenance');
        this._super();
      }
  });
};

export default {
  name: 'maintenance-redirect',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Once you're done delete it.